# Complete InfoPath form without InfoPath external customer

Tags: infopath

I need to create a form that our customers will complete but not all of our customers will have InfoPath installed.

I tried to use the email form but did not show the form in Outlook, instead it just displayed the xml code

My question is what is the best type of from to create and how to allow external customers to view and complete the form

Thanks

Comment: Are you got your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

For users that do not have the InfoPath client installed, you'll want to create a Browser Enabled InfoPath form.

This will let your external users open and complete the form using their web browser.

For further details, please refer here: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Introduction-to-browser-compatible-form-templates-7a6e40ff-eb1d-4311-945d-169857d340af?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA

Note that depending on the version of SharePoint & InfoPath that you're using, and the type of external users (e.g. company contractors vs. the general public) you may or may not need an Enterprise CAL (Client Access License) for each user.

Comment: I have checked my form and it is set to be completed in a web browser

http://i62.tinypic.com/16kvqbk.png
http://i58.tinypic.com/2mzcp5t.png